# Display sums of memory usage of "similar processes"

Tags: command-line, memory

1. I want to have a whole list of all the processes with their memory usage.
2. I want to sum up the memory usage of similar processes (i.e. processes with the same name or the same father process)

How can I do that, e.g. with command line tools?

Answer (score 6):

There are many commandline tools

`ps` which can be used to view processes their cpu usage etc. Just try `ps aux`.

`top` for system monitoring

`htop` is top with better readability

and there `free`, `vmstat` and `pmap` as well.

View respective man pages. i.e. man ps

Answer (score 0):

I think `htop` is so far good. You need to install it by `apt-get install htop`. Also `top` command good as build-in.