# Getting aggregate memory usage of a Linux process?

Tags: command-line, ram, memory-usage, monitoring

How is it possible to aggregate memory usage of a Linux process and all its children in human readable format?

I tried [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111397/display-sums-of-memory-usage-of-similar-processes) and even using `cat /proc/$pid/status` but the latter had 18GB of VirtualMemory for chrome on my machine which only has 12GB of RAM (I know it is virtual and can be higher than physical RAM amount). But I need to know the **physical** memory usage of all chrome instances at once and at the moment.

Comment: You could create a cgroup for it, and either start it in the cgroup or move the process and all its children into the cgroup after the fact.  Then the cgoup will keep track of aggregate max RSS.  (A full answer for this should include how to create the cgroup and read out the details.)

Comment: @user10489 I prefer an approach with available commands and tools, not a custom homemad. In windows it's very easy and intuitive on its own system monitor.